# Pump Terminology: Suction Piping vs Suction Waterway

Tags: pumps

Karassik and McGuire state in their 2012 book, [1] p. 415,

> The available energy that can be utilized to get the liquid through the **suction piping** and **suction waterway** of the pump into the impeller is thus the total suction head less the vapor pressure of the liquid at the pumping temperature

My question is: what is the **suction piping** and the **suction waterway** and what is the difference between the two?

## References

[1] McGuire, J. T., Karassik, I. (2012). Centrifugal Pumps. United States: Springer US.
https://www.google.com/books/edition/Centrifugal_Pumps/KEzjBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22suction+waterway%22+pump&pg=PA415&printsec=frontcover

Answer (score 0):

(Suction) Waterways are the internals of pump.  Suction Piping extends head of pump.  Suction Waterways and Suction Piping must be full of water for efficient pump operation.

The suction piping increases the pump waterways to allow the pump to work.

Page 686 from Book

> A centrifugal pump is primed when the **waterways** of the pump are filled with the liquid to be pumped.  The liquid replaces the air, gas or vapor in the **waterways**.  Removal of the air, gas, or vapor may be done manually or automatically.

In addition to the internals, piping can be added to the pump body to increase head.  From Page 416 for NPSH (net positive suction head) (All appear to be equivalent):
[image]